# Insert elements to a table inside other table

Tags: lua

I need help to know how to do for use table.insert, and insert elements in to one table that is in to another table.  This what i have:

```
Table = {} --Main table

function InsertNewValues()

local TIME = --Any value, string or integer
local SIGNAL = --Any value, string or integer
table.insert(Table, {TIME, SIGNAL})

end
```

Ok, this allow me to insert the values of TIME and SIGNAL everytime i call that function, so the table will have:

```
Table[1][1] = TIME
Table[1][2] = SINGAL
...
Table[...][1] = TIME
Table[...][2] = SIGNAL
```

BUT ... I need to insert the values of TIME and SIGNAL in to another table that is inside of the table "Table", and that table work as a KEY to refer those values ... TIME and SIGNAL ...

therefore, the resulting table would be the following:

```
+Table
|
+-[1]othertable
|
+-+[1]TIME - [2]SIGNAL
+-+[1]TIME - [2]SIGNAL
+- ...
|
+-[2]othertable
|
+-+[1]TIME - [2]SIGNAL
+-+[1]TIME - [2]SIGNAL
+- ...
```

How can i do for do that?

----------------- EDIT -----------------

I have not explained myself well, what I need is:

Given a table called "Table", I need to be able to use "strings" as "keys" within that table. That would be:

```
-- Name of my "container" table
Table = {}
```

Values to be introduced

```
Time = '1 seconds' -- this value can change as desired
Value = 'logic' -- this value can change as desired
```

Add to my master table "Table", using the string key "RandomName"

```
-- "RandomName" can change as desired

function AddNewValues ()
   table.insert (Table [RandomName], {Time, Value})
end
```

Every time I call the function "AddNewValues ()", it should add the values present in "Time" and "Value" as a "NEW ENTRY" for that "RandomName".

So the table result may should look like this:

```
+table -- that contains
+-RandomName-- string key to access
+--"Time,Value"
+--"Time,Value"
+--"Time,Value"
+...
```

And then, to be able to access the values that are inside that table, using "RandomName" as the key:

```
function Load()
  for key, v in pairs(Table) do
    a = Table[key][RandomName][1] -- reference to "Time"
    b = Table[key][RandomName][2] -- reference to "Value"
    print('Time: ' .. a ..'/' .. 'Value: ' .. b)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just not starting deep enough into the table. When you want the sequence values for the table under the key equaling the value of RandomName, just do:

```
function Load()
  for _, v in ipairs(Table[RandomName]) do
    a = v[1] -- reference to "Time"
    b = v[RandomName][2] -- reference to "Value"
    print('Time: ' .. a ..'/' .. 'Value: ' .. b)
  end
end
```

---

Answer to original question:

It appears that you want something like this:

```
Table = { ["[1]othertable"] = {}, ["[2]othertable"] = {} }
table.insert(Table["[1]othertable"],  {TIME, SIGNAL})
```

The keys are "[1]othertable" and "[2]othertable".

You might prefer to use keys like "othertable1" and "othertable2". If you use valid identifiers you can drop some of the syntax:

```
Table = { othertable1 = {}, othertable2 = {} }
table.insert(Table.othertable1,  {TIME, SIGNAL})
```

In fact, you might prefer to do something similar with TIME and SIGNAL. Instead of positive integer indices, you could use string keys:

```
Table = { othertable1 = {}, othertable2 = {} }
table.insert(Table.othertable1,  {TIME = 12.42, SIGNAL = 3.2})
print(Table.othertable1[1].TIME)
```